# Removing TextView before recreating it

Tags: android, textview

here i have a custom TextView with animation :

```
 badge7 = new BadgeView(this,findViewById(R.id.action_contact));
        badge7.hide();
        badge7.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        badge7.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        text++;
        badge7.setText(String.valueOf(text));
        badge7.setTextSize(12);
        badge7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.badge_ifaux);
        badge7.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_LEFT);
        badge7.setBadgeMargin(15, 10);


        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(-100, 0, 0, 0);
        anim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(2000);
        anim.cancel();
        badge7.toggle(anim, null);
```

the problem is whenever the animation is played again, i need the last one to be removed from screen, but that i couldnt make it happen, what is the correct way to do so guys?

Answer (score 0):

well, found the solution:

```
 if(badge7!=null){
        badge7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        badge7.invalidate();
        }
```